# How do I tranfer bitcoins from my Zebpay wallet to my blockchain wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet, transaction-fees

I have some bitcoins in my zebpay wallet. How do I tranfer these bitcoins to my blockchain wallet. Is there any transaction fee for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "**Request**" tab on blockchain wallet, it will give you a bitcoin address where your bitcoins will be transferred from your zebpay wallet.
Then find "**send**" or similar button on your zebpay wallet and copy&paste the bitcoin address you previously acquired from blockchain wallet to here.

Zebpay probably cut a commission fee for this transaction. You can find info on their website how much they will charge for the transaction.